# C# Webhook InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks

Tags: c#, nuget, webhooks

I receive the error:

'HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks' and no accessible extension method 'InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have the HttpConfiguration DLL and I have also installed the ASPNet Webhooks Reciever package.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    // Initialize Generic JSON WebHook receiver
    config.InitializeReceiveGenericJsonWebHooks();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you missed the "Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Generic" nuget package. After installing it, your compiler error should disappear.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019, go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console.  Then execute the command: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Generic -Version 1.2.2`
Where 1.2.2 is the version number, yours may be different.